# Buildfire: Is there any API method to access the intro slides?

Tags: buildfire

The intro slides feature of buildfire was working with no issues until recently. I am unable to view and edit my intro slides. I can only keep creating...
Has anyone had this issue???

https://ibb.co/1r7V9TT

Comment: This seems like a customer support issue and not a coding issue. Have you tried contacting support?

Comment: I have, they have submitted a ticket a few days ago.